# Can I incorporate TrustedGRUB code into GRUB2?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, boot, grub

We have a TPM on our box and GRUB2 needs to unseal the keys in the TPM during boot time. We have a UEFI-based box. But, GRUb2 doesn't have support for unsealing the keys. However TrustedGRUB has support for unsealing keys but doesn't run on UEFI systems.
Is it possible to incorporate the TPM related code into GRUB2?
Has anyone already tried this before?

Comment: Do you run without an initramfs? Usually that's just done using Linux tools from within the initrd, not by requiring the bootloader to support anything extra.

Comment: Yeah. We need to do this operation (unsealing of TPM keys) in GRUB2 and validate/decrypt the kernel and boot it up.